# Is $ \sin 2x \ge 0 $ same as $\sin x\cos x\ge 0 $?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Or differently phrased do $$ \sin 2x \ge 0$$  $$\sin x\cos x\ge 0 $$   have the same solution.

$\sin 2x$ is positive from  $ 0\le x \le \pi/2$ , while $\sin x\cos x$ are positive in the first and third quadrant. Why is this, when $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$, am i making a mistake.

***Does this mean i cannot use double angle identity under the square root?***

Edit: as vadim123 said the question was wrong, so i changed it

Comment: `sin2x is positive from 0 ≤ x ≤ π/2` And also for $\pi \le x \le 3 \pi/2$.

Comment: @dxiv can you explain that a bit

Comment: The question and title are asking different things.

Comment: $\pi \le x \le 3 \pi/2 \iff 2 \pi \le 2x \le 3 \pi \implies \sin 2x \ge 0\,$. `sinx cosx are positive in the first and third quadrant` And so is $\sin 2x$.

Comment: @dxiv i still dont how we got $3π/2$, i get that when you divide it by 2 you are back in the second quadrant(so 3π/2 is correct). But i dont know how to get $3π/2$ in the first place

Comment: @MilanStojanovic Look at [$y = \sin 2x$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(2x)+for+0+%3C%3D+x+%3C%3D+2+pi) and see where it is $\,\ge 0\,$.

Comment: @MilanStojanovic The function $\sin(2x)$ has a period of $\pi$. That means it repeats itself every $\pi$ such that $\sin(2x)=\sin(2(x+\pi))$. In the period from $[0,\pi)$, it's non-negative on $[0,\pi/2]$. Therefore, by periodicity, it is also nonnegative on $[\pi,3\pi/2]$

Comment: @zahbaz thanks .

Comment: "Is sin2x≥0
same as sinxcosx≥0
?"  Only in the same sense that $97 \ge 0$ is the same as $52 \ge 0$.  To say $f(x) \ge 0$ has the same solutions as $g(x) \ge 0$ means only that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ will always have the same sign.  It does not mean that $f(x) = g(x)$.  It should be obvious that $2\cos x \sin x$ and $\cos x\sin x$ will always have the same sign even though they can only be equal when they both equal $0$.

Comment: @MilanStojanovic Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$

$$\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$$

we have that in general

$$|\sin 2x|=|2\sin x\cos x|\neq |\sin x\cos x|$$

but

$$\sin 2x\ge 0 \iff 2\sin x\cos x\ge 0 \iff \sin x\cos x\ge 0 $$

therefore $ \sin 2x \ge 0$ and $\sin x\cos x\ge 0 $ have the same solutions.

Comment: $|\mathit{whatever}|\ge 0$ is always true...

Comment: @HenningMakholm Opsss sorry, I fix that disaster! I don't know what I was thinking about. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how to get those solution (looking at the unit circle, for example)

Comment: @MilanStojanovic Simply note that $\sin \theta \ge 0$ for $0+2k\pi\le \theta \le \pi + 2k\pi$ therefore $\sin 2x \ge 0$ for $2k\pi\le 2x \le \pi + 2k\pi$ that is for $$k\pi\le x \le \frac{\pi}2 + k\pi$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, i forgot to divide the period by 2

Comment: @MilanStojanovic You are welcome. In general in these cases write down the solution for a generic $\theta$ and the substitute for the expression with $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Just because $\sin(2x)$ and $\sin(x)\cos (x)$ always have the same *sign* (which is true) doesn't mean they have the same *magnitude*. $|\sin(2x)|$ is twice as large as $|\sin(x)\cos(x)|$, so they are not the same (except when they are both $0$).

---

(When this answer was posted, the title of the question asked about $|\sin 2x|$ and $|\sin x \cos x|$. The OP later removed the absolute-value signs without comment).

Comment: I made a mistake when asking the question. That wasnt what i wanted to ask , sorry. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere you can use $\sin(2x)$ you can also use $2\sin(x)\cos(x)$. This is an identity. We can show this using the double angle formula:

$$\sin(a + b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) + \sin(b)\cos(a) \implies \sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$$

Your question is asking if the solution to $\sin(2x)\ge0$ is the same as that of $\sin(x)\cos(x)\ge0$. Indeed, if we multiply the latter by $2$, we see that the solution must be the same! Why? Because $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ is an identity: they're two representations of the same mathematical object!

Either inequality is thus solved by $x +\pi n$ such that $x\in[0,\pi/2]$ with integer $n$. This is because $\sin(2x)$ is $\pi$ periodic. Written another way, we could use the periodicity to write that the inequality is satisfied for $$x\in \dots[-\pi,-\pi/2]\cup[0,\pi/2]\cup[\pi,3\pi/2]\cup\dots$$

Answer (score 1):

Note if $M > 0$ then $M*a*b > 0$ if $a > 0; b>0$ or $a < 0; b< 0$.  And $M*a*b < 0$ if $a < 0; b > 0$ or $a > 0; b < 0$.  And $M*a*b = 0$ if $a = 0$ or $b =0$.  It does not matter whether $M =1$ or $M = 2$ or $M = \frac {37.95}{\pi}$.

So we would expect $\cos x \sin x \ge 0$ for the *exact* same values of $x$ as we would expect $\sin 2x = 2\cos x \sin x\ge 0$ or for the *exact* same values we would expect $\frac {37.95}{\pi}\cos x \sin x \ge 0$.

And it works out to be exactly the case.  $\cos x \sin x \ge 0$ if $x$ is in the first or third quadrant (as those are the two quadrants where $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are both the same sign.)  And $\sin M \ge 0$ if $M$ is in the first or second quadrant.  And  $M = 2x$ is in the first quadrant if $x$ is in the first half of the first or third quadrant.  ANd $M$ is in the second quadrant if $x$ is in the second half of the first or third quadrant.

Or in other words:

If $0 \le x \le \frac \pi 2$ then $\sin x \ge 0$ and $\cos x \ge 0$ so $\sin x\cos x \ge 0$.  Also $0 \le 2x \le \pi$ so $\sin 2x \ge 0$.

If $\frac \pi 2 \le x \le \pi$ then $\sin x \ge 0$ and $\cos x \le 0$ so $\sin x\cos x \le 0$.  Also $\pi \le 2x \le 2\pi$ so $\sin 2x \le 0$.

If $\pi \le x \le \frac {3\pi} 2$ then $\sin x \le 0$ and $\cos x \le 0$ so $\sin x\cos x \ge 0$.  Also $2\pi \le 2x \le 3\pi$ so $\sin 2x \ge 0$.

If $\frac {3\pi} 2 \le x \le 2\pi$ then $\sin x \le 0$ and $\cos x \ge 0$ so $\sin x\cos x \le 0$.  Also $3\pi \le 2x \le 4\pi$ so $\sin 2x \le 0$.

As well $\sin 2x = 2\cos x\sin x$  and $\cos x\sin x$ and $M*\cos x \sin x; M > 0$ should all be $> 0$ if $\cos x, \sin x$ are the same sign, and should all be $< 0$ of $\cos x, \sin y$ are opposite signs, and should $= 0$ if one or the other of $\cos x, \sin x$ equals $0$.  So all turns out to work exactly as it should.